# Adding activity re-sizing feature

Tags: android

I have a activity which I want to resize based on user event.I tried `getWindow.setLayout()` inside `onTouchListener` but the resizing is not smooth at all.Please provide some suggestions.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not smooth at all"? What happens when you call `setLayout()`?

Answer (score -1):

Please Use Absolute layout. I think, that will help